# class diagram generator for .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, reflection, designer, class-diagram

I would like to create one of those pretty looking class diagrams for some of our libraries wich are .NET based. The final goal is to build a pretty looking poster that could potentially be shipped together with the library CD or could be used for other promotional purposes.

The class diagram should list the main classes and their type hierarchy arranged by some custom categories and with some comments/documentation what each class represents.

So the actual requirements for the generator are as followed:

- It should automatically generate the diagram from a .NET assembly (not the visual studio project).
- After the class diagram is generated I should still be able to author the look of the diagram (e.g. change colors, shapes and positions, draw some extra rectangles around things, add additional text).

The following would be a "nice to have":

- I should be able to prefilter what classes should be included or not included in the diagram to be generated. Ideally by some sort of language (c#, regular expressions) but simple checkboxes to deselect parts of the tree probably would do too.

The best solution would probably be a small .NET lib that I could use, that help me reflect over the assembly, search for types and that also has some APIs to create the block graphics from the types (HTML, SVG, XAML ?).

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty complex undertaking. You'd have to have a parser that can deal with LINQ and C# or VB syntax and dependencies, and know which classes to ignore and keep etc. Plus layout. It's not going to happen in a natural way that makes sense to humans if fully automated.

Chceck this one out:

http://www.aivosto.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some [add-ins for reflector.net](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/), which can produce class diagrams from .NET assemblies (e.g. [Assembly Visualizer](http://www.denismarkelov.com/p/assembly-visualizer.html), [AutoDiagrammer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17823/100-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool) and Graph). Although I don't know if they fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional suggestions:

- http://www.nwoods.com/components/dotnet/webforms-samples.htm
- http://www.nevron.com/Products.DiagramFor.NET.Overview.aspx
- http://www.mindfusion.eu/features-netdiagram.html